# Tesseract (Tess4j) increasing accuracy

Tags: opencv, tesseract, tess4j

Am making a licence plate recognition software, I already trained my language using `SunnyPage 2.7`, currently the detection is good except Tesseract is not giving me good results. For example it reads [This plate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRr5r.png) as `AC2 4529` well thats good except when I load the same image in `SunnyPage` with my language I get `ACZ 4529` which is correct, I ended up configuring Tesseract to `tess.setPageSegMode(10) single character mode` segmenting the individual characters and processing each character one by one in Tesseract, that increased accuracy but not as much, below is my Tesseract configuration

```
 Tesseract instance = new Tesseract(); //
    instance.setLanguage(LANGUAGE);
    instance.setHocr(false);
    instance.setTessVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ACPBZRT960847152");
    instance.setTessVariable("load_system_dawg", "false");
    instance.setTessVariable("load_freq_dawg", "false");

    instance.setOcrEngineMode(TessOcrEngineMode.OEM_CUBE_ONLY);
    instance.setPageSegMode(TessPageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_CHAR);
    instance.setPageSegMode(10);
```

Anyone know How I can get results as good as `SunnyPage`? as far as I know my image is good, it is `skewed` and well segmented so it is most likely to do with Tesseract alone.

Comment: It's unlikely that your `traineddata` file is cube, so comment out `setOcrEngineMode` statement to use the default mode and run again to see if you get better results.

Comment: Well nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to train tesseract with actual images of your license plates. This will make your results much more accurate because tesseract will actually know what a Z and 2 look like and it will recognize them much more accurately.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract

http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html